Dynamic content projection of an array of components wrapped in another component
I want to dynamically project a rendered component inside a wrapping component so I can wrap some other HTML around it. Unfortunately, this pattern has been implemented across an app, and refactoring it to  is a challenge. It is possible to achieve this with the current markup shown in the Main app HTML?
Main app HTML
<fs-chips>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let chip of chips">
    <fs-chip   
        [value]="chip">
      {{chip.name}}
    </fs-chip>
  </ng-container>
</fs-chips>

FsChipsComponent HTML
<ng-container *ngFor="let chip of chips">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Project each fs-chip here -->
  </div>
</ng-container>


You can only achieve this by passing a template to your component and using *ngTemplateOutlet to render it in the right place like this. Or by using the angular cdk domportal
